# Redirect after form submission with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, redirect, http-redirect

In my form, I have a user enter in a link, and my goal is to redirect to that link. However, my problem is that whenever I try and get the user to redirect, the form wont redirect to the page. Several people have recommended this:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="blah blah blah" id="url">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return submit_form()">
</form>
```

```js
function submit_form(){
  window.location.href="a url";
  return false;
}
```

However, when I do this, my server does not receive the input by the user. How can I fix this?

Edit: 
I have also tried this:

```js
function submit(){
  url = getElementById("url").value;
  window.location.href = "url";

}
```

Comment: 1. Assign an `id` to your url input. 2. Fetch the value in your function by using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). 3. Use the fetched value to redirect the user using [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Comment: I have tried doing that. That does not work

Comment: Post that code, in that case.

Comment: Show code of how the submit works. the posting, is it done raw with just html?

Comment: It is done with raw html, except for the redirect. The server then gets the information from the from submit

Comment: Why does the client need to tell the server where to redirect? Something tells me you aren't submitting this form to your own server or code, and therefore need to somehow bypass what that server is currently doing while still sending it data. Which... is an entirely different scenario than what is presented in your question.

Comment: I am submitting this to my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use browser javascript to set `window.location.href` to a URL, your browser immediately navigates to that URL without intervention from your server.  It's similar to typing a URL into the browser's location bar.

If you want your server to do the navigation you need a more complex setup.  On your browser, something like this.

```
<form action="/your/server/route">
  <input type=hidden" name="redirect" value="https://example.com/where/to/redirect">
  <input type="text" name="blah blah blah">
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Then in your node code handling `/your/server/route` ...

```
if (req.body.redirect) res.redirect(req.body.redirect)
```

That way your server tells the browser to redirect as part of handling the post of your form.

**Security tip** cybercreeps can misuse the situation where you pass a redirect URL from a browser to your server. Always validate `req.body.redirect` to make sure it matches what you expect before you use it to actually redirect.

Comment: How could they pass a redirect URL? And how can I validate?

Comment: Only somebody who understands your application can answer these questions. How does your redirect capability serve your users?